# configure: error: could not locate a valid LDAP library (pam_ldap library)

Tags: cross-compiling, openldap, configure

I am trying to cross-compile the pam_ldap library from source code for ARM architecture.
The configure command gives me this error:

```
checking for main in -llber... no
checking for main in -lldap... no
configure: error: could not locate a valid LDAP library
```

Is the libldap.so what it's looking for? Have I to give it's path in the LDFLAGS variable?
My configure command looks like this:

```
./configure --prefix=/path/to/local/directory/ --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf CPPFLAGS="-I/path/to/ldap.h/include/directory/" --with-ldap-dir=/path/to/openldap/source/files/ --with-ldap-lib=openldap LDFLAGS="-L/path/to/directory/where/libldap.so/is/located/ontheTarget/"
```

Can anyone please give me a hint?
Thank you.

Comment: Yes, `configure` is looking for library it could not find on your system. Did you cross-compile an `LDAP` library first ?

Comment: Yes, that was the cause of the problem, I cross compiled a wrong wersion of LDAP library. Thank you.